# Neo4j 3.0.6 : Impossible to connect to remote shell

Tags: neo4j, rmi

I have a strange bug as I'm unable to connect to remote shell with neo4j 3.0.6 from a machine A to B. The server B (ip address192.168.10.204)  hosts Neo4j.
All these machines runs Debian 8 and neo4j 3.0.6

First, `dbms.shell.enabled=true and dbms.shell.host=0.0.0.0` (and port) are of course set in neo4j.conf

I dig into this bug and got several situations.

At the begining, when I launched shell in machine A :

```
Shell$ ./neo4j-shell -host 192.168.10.204 -port 1337 -v

Welcome to the Neo4j Shell! Enter 'help' for a list of commands NOTE: Remote Neo4j graph database service 'shell' at port 1337

neo4j-sh (?)$ return "1"; Connection refused to host: 127.0.1.1; nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused neo4j-sh (?)$ Shell$
```

Digging deeply in this bug, I played with /etc/hosts file and RMI flags and tried different things (for instance by commenting line with 127.0.1.1 address)

My situation now :

```
/etc/hosts
127.0.0.1    localhost
127.0.1.1    debian-jessie.vagrantup.com    debian-jessie
```

The flags I add in neo4j-wrapper.conf are these :

```
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=debian-jessie.vagrantup.com -Dremoting.bind_by_host=false
```

Now Neo4j accept to start, I can try to connect remotely, so I get :

```
$ ./neo4j-shell -host 192.168.10.204 -port 1337 -v
ERROR (-v for expanded information):
    Unknown host: debian-jessie.vagrantup.com; nested exception is: 
    java.net.UnknownHostException: debian-jessie.vagrantup.com
java.rmi.UnknownHostException: Unknown host: debian-jessie.vagrantup.com; nested exception is: 
    java.net.UnknownHostException: debian-jessie.vagrantup.com
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:616)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:130)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:227)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:179)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.welcome(Unknown Source)
    at org.neo4j.shell.impl.AbstractClient.sayHi(AbstractClient.java:257)
    at org.neo4j.shell.impl.RemoteClient.findRemoteServer(RemoteClient.java:70)
    at org.neo4j.shell.impl.RemoteClient.<init>(RemoteClient.java:62)
    at org.neo4j.shell.impl.RemoteClient.<init>(RemoteClient.java:45)
    at org.neo4j.shell.ShellLobby.newClient(ShellLobby.java:204)
    at org.neo4j.shell.StartClient.startRemote(StartClient.java:358)
    at org.neo4j.shell.StartClient.start(StartClient.java:229)
    at org.neo4j.shell.StartClient.main(StartClient.java:147)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: debian-jessie.vagrantup.com
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:148)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
```

I tested a random port (like 50587, RMI used to use these kind of ports) to know if they are closed by default in my linux, and they are open.

Answer (score -1):

```
/etc/hosts
127.0.0.1    localhost
127.0.1.1    debian-jessie.vagrantup.com    debian-jessie
```

The problem is here. `debian-jessie.vagrantup.com` should be mapped to its real IP address, not 127.0.0.1, and not nothing. Or else it shouldn't be mapped at all, if the DNS system can provide it.

Comment: It doesn't work.
I replaced 127.0.1.1 by the ip address (192.168.10.204)
And I also tryed to add a new host for this  address, both strategy doesn't work with exactly the same exception..

Comment: If that hostname appears in the hosts file of the host that got the exception, you can't get that exception.

Comment: EJP : Here's my hosts, after your comment.
192.168.10.204      debian-jessie.vagrantup.com     debian-jessie
I got exactly the same stacktrace. I you don't believe me, I can give you a screenshot